# Automatic Triggering of GitHub repo pushes in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, ngrok, github-webhook

I am trying to create a GitHub webhook to connect a GitHub repo and Jenkins(docker container) server -- for triggering Jenkins build automatically when there are repo pushes, I am using ngrok to expose the Jenkins address/repo to get a payload URL for the GitHub webhook.
I have done all this, when testing the Payload URL in GitHub, it returned a ping 502 error.
I would appreciate any help, if anyone has connected a Jenkins server and GitHub repo for automatic triggering, thanks.

I expected the GitHub webhook -- ngrok payload URL to send a successful ping